# Do not open a new instance of an application, if it's already open in another workspace in Mint

Tags: linux-mint, window, workspaces

I am using Linux Mint and I enabled multiple workspaces. 
Suppose I have an instance of an application (i.e., Google Chrome) open on Workspace 1. When I switch to Workspace 2 and I open Google Chrome, I would like to be redirected to the instance already open on WorkSpace 1, while Linux makes me open another (new) window on Workspace 2. This is a bit annoying.

Is there a way to prevent Linux Mint to open a new instance of an application, if there is another one already open in another Workspace?

Comment: But... isn't that the normal behavior even if you try to open the same program in the same workspace? I think it doesn't depend on the Desktop Environment but in the program itself. I mean, what happens if you try to open Google Chrome in the same workspace where you already have a Google Chrome instance open?